# forecully exit from the catch block

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Please find my code here :

Basically the connection to database located at aa.aa.a.aaa failed and I keep on getting the following error:

```
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
SQLState: 08S01
VendorError: 0
SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
SQLState: 08S01
VendorError: 0
SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
SQLState: 08S01
VendorError: 0
SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
SQLState: 08S01
VendorError: 0
SQLException: Communications link failure
```

Is there a way, I can quit from the Catch block so that the error stops printing after one time letting the user know , okay the error has occured and then move onto the next IP addresses starting from bb.bb.b.bbb and so on..

My code is as follows,

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import static com.Ostermiller.util.StringHelper.escapeSQL;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ResultsReader extends Task<Integer> {
    private static int NumberOfResultsThreads = 10;
    private static int NumberOfResultsContactsToProcessPerThread = 1000;
    private static int NumberOfRecordsToInsertAtATime = 100;

    private int CurrModValue;
    private static String IP[];

    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        int iterations = 0;
        int i = 0;
        // boolean done = false;
        Statement SelectResultsStmt = null;
        Statement UpdateResultsStmt = null;
        Statement InsertRemoteResultsStmt = null;
        Statement InsertRemoteResultsErrorLogStmt = null;
        ResultSet SelectResultsRS = null;
        Connection connRemote = null;
        Connection connRemoteforCatch = null;

        while (i <= 5) {
            try {
                Connection[] MainConnection = new Connection[5];
                String[] RemoteIPAddress = new String[5];

                RemoteIPAddress[0] = "aa.aa.a.aaa";
                RemoteIPAddress[1] = "bb.bb.b.bbb";
                RemoteIPAddress[2] = "cc.cc.c.ccc";
                RemoteIPAddress[3] = "dd.dd.d.ddd";
                RemoteIPAddress[4] = "ee.ee.e.eee";
                RemoteIPAddress[5] = "ff.ff.f.fff";
                RemoteIPAddress[6] = "gg.gg.g.ggg";

                MainConnection[0] = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RemoteIPAddress[0] + ":3306/test", RemoteUser, RemotePass);
                MainConnection[1] = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RemoteIPAddress[1] + ":3306/test", RemoteUser, RemotePass);
                MainConnection[2] = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RemoteIPAddress[2] + ":3306/test", RemoteUser, RemotePass);
                MainConnection[3] = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RemoteIPAddress[3] + ":3306/test", RemoteUser, RemotePass);
                MainConnection[4] = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RemoteIPAddress[4] + ":3306/test", RemoteUser, RemotePass);
                MainConnection[5] = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RemoteIPAddress[5] + ":3306/test", RemoteUser, RemotePass);
                MainConnection[6] = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RemoteIPAddress[6] + ":3306/test", RemoteUser, RemotePass);

                Connection connRemote = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.x.xxx:3306/test", MainUser, MainPass);
                String QueryString = " SELECT "+ " // my table fields here+ " + " FROM "+ " RemoteIPtable "+ " ;

                SelectResultsStmt = MainConnection[i].createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                SelectResultsRS = SelectResultsStmt.executeQuery(QueryString);
                                                    int CurrentBillingAmount = 0;
                                                    int CurrentRowCount = 0;
                                                    String QueryStringInsertFromRemote = "";

                while (SelectResultsRS.next() ) {
                    CurrentRowCount++;

                    QueryStringInsertFromRemote = " INSERT INTO mytabletest "
                        + " ( " + " + " + " + "" + " ) " 
                        + " VALUES " 
                        + " ( " + " NULL, " + " " + " ) ";

                    InsertRemoteResultsStmt = connRemote.createStatement();
                    InsertRemoteResultsStmt.executeUpdate(QueryStringInsertFromRemote);
                    // reset string to empty
                    QueryStringInsertFromRemote = "";
                    SelectResultsRS.updateRow();
                }

                System.out.println("IP Just Completed is:" + RemoteIPAddress[i]);
                i++;

                System.out.println("Value of i is :" + i);
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) {

                System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            } 
        } // END Of WHILE 
    } 
    return iterations;
}
```

I read somewhere on SOF that , someone advised to use `continue` statement after the end of catch block but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes .. do this ..

```
...
boolean flag = false;
while (i <= 5) {
...
try{ ... }
catch (SQLException ex) {
    if(!flag){
       System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
       System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
       System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
       flag = true; 

    }
    i++;
}
...
```

Comment: Doing this does displayed the error for only one time but my loop didn't move forward to process other database connections.It seems like my loop isn't moving forward. Anything else you would suggest?

Comment: try my code with the little modification I made, and let me know. I added `i++`

Comment: It's back to where I was. Printing same messages over and over again :(

Comment: I can strongly say that what you put in your code is not the above code. Please double check. I've already checked this.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working at my end. I have checked many times. Perhaps, some other approach is required here. I hope the `i++` in my try block is not interfering ?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean flag = false; //declare boolean variable

while (i <= 5) {
 //Your code

  try { ... 

  }  catch (SQLException ex) {

    if(flag){
     continue;
    }

    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    flag = true;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Your's is not even printing the SQL Exception error messages